# For loop that outputs 0,-1,1,-2,2,-3,3

Tags: java, for-loop

I am making a Java game and am trying to get blocks to spawn alternating back and forth on the x-axis using a for loop.

Comment: so what's your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do something like this:

```
spawn(0);

for(int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i)
{
    spawn(-i);
    spawn( i);
}
```

Comment: `spawn( -i )` should be before `spawn( i )`

Comment: I'm sure in OP's situation it would make no practical difference, but sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
Method createBlock(): //creates the blocks at desired x axis 

createBlock(0); //initial block placed at 0
int howMany= input
for (i=0; howMany;i++){
    createBlock(-i)
    createBlock(i)
}
```

Comment: or ya know... what michael said. =/

Answer (score 0):

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i >= 0 ? -i - 1 : -i). limit(100).forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.print(0);
    for (int i = 1; i<=3; i++) {
        System.out.print(String.format(",%s,%s", -i, i));
    }
```